# Why can't I change the svg pathlengh at all?

Tags: svg, framer-motion

I can't change the pathLength of the following svg at all. I tried it with framer-motion, but also by adding the pathLength attribute manually. Nothing, the path doesn't grow, shrink or do anything at all. Here's the code:

```
<motion.svg className={styles.loaderIconOld}
                preserveAspectRatio='none'
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 264.58 264.58">
                <g id="layer3" transform="translate(0 -32.417)" >
                    <motion.path
                        variants={pathVariants}
                        initial='hidden'
                        animate='visible'
                        transition={{
                            duration: 2, ease: "easeInOut",
                        }}
                         d="m98.161 132.79-11.239-1.2374v-5.1557h27.325l14.539 46.401 3.4027 13.095 3.0934-13.095 14.436-46.401h27.119v5.1557l-11.342 1.2374 8.2491 64.033 8.9709 1.1342v5.0526h-29.697v-5.0526l9.3833-1.0311-4.6401-46.298-2.1654-19.901-4.3308 14.848-17.22 53.928h-6.7024l-16.704-49.391-6.0837-19.488-1.856 20.004-4.1245 46.298 10.208 1.0311v5.0526h-26.913v-5.0526l8.7646-1.0311z" fill="#fff" stroke="#000" strokeWidth=".26458" />
                </g>
        </motion.svg>
```

Here are the pathVariants:

```
const pathVariants = {
    hidden: {
        opacity: 0,
        pathLength: 0,
    },
    visible: {
        opacity: 1,
        pathLength: 1,
    }
}
```

The opacity does animate, but the SVG itself isn't being line-drawn. Could it be that only certain SVGs work? I am really bamboozled at this problem.
Many thanks!

Comment: It's implemented only as an attribute currently but change has been proposed: https://github.com/w3c/svgwg/issues/773

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Robert Longson pointed out, using `pathLength` in CSS is currently not supported. But even if it was, the result of an animation would not be what you expect. The [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/paths.html#PathLengthAttribute) defines:

> This value is used to calibrate the user agent's own distance-along-a-path calculations with that of the author. The user agent will scale all distance-along-a-path computations by the ratio of ‘pathLength’ to the user agent's own computed value for total path length.

The attribute does not change what portion of a path is painted, it only changes the interpretation of values used in **other** places. That could be, for example, a `stroke-dashoffset` value. Suppose you set `stroke-dashoffset="1"`. If `pathLength="1"`, the offset is at the end of the path; if `pathLength="2"`, it is at the midpoint. To bring the offset to the start of the path, `pathLength` would have to be Infinity.

That also brings up the question: what means `pathLength="0"`?

> A value of zero is valid and must be treated as a scaling factor of infinity. A value of zero scaled infinitely must remain zero, while any non-percentage value greater than zero must become `+Infinity`.

All that makes animating `pathLength` uncomfortable, as you constantly have to think about inverse values. It is more straightforward to animate the *other* value - even though it still has its sticking points. With the commonly used [trick](https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/), what you want to achieve looks like this *(avoid using 1 as a length value, you could run into rounding issues)*:

```
<motion.svg className={styles.loaderIconOld}
        preserveAspectRatio='none'
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 264.58 264.58">
        <g id="layer3" transform="translate(0 -32.417)" >
            <motion.path
                variants={pathVariants}
                initial='hidden'
                animate='visible'
                transition={{
                    duration: 2, ease: "easeInOut",
                }}
                pathLength=10
                strokeDasharray=10
                 d="m98.161 132.79-11.239-1.2374v-5.1557h27.325l14.539 46.401 3.4027 13.095 3.0934-13.095 14.436-46.401h27.119v5.1557l-11.342 1.2374 8.2491 64.033 8.9709 1.1342v5.0526h-29.697v-5.0526l9.3833-1.0311-4.6401-46.298-2.1654-19.901-4.3308 14.848-17.22 53.928h-6.7024l-16.704-49.391-6.0837-19.488-1.856 20.004-4.1245 46.298 10.208 1.0311v5.0526h-26.913v-5.0526l8.7646-1.0311z" fill="#fff" stroke="#000" strokeWidth=".26458" />
        </g>
</motion.svg>

const pathVariants = {
    hidden: {
        opacity: 0,
        strokeDashoffset: -10,
    },
    visible: {
        opacity: 1,
        strokeDashoffset: 0,
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation and code suggestion. Unfortunately, absolutely nothing changed. I tried editing the strokeDashoffset and strokeDasharray manually as well, in the Chrome dev tools, but to no avail, no chance was visible. I will now try to figure it out with an easier example in a blank page. I'll post a solution if I find one.

Comment: Remember: it's `strokeDashoffset` in React, but `stroke-dashoffset` as a plain attribute/CSS property.

Comment: So after quite some dabbling, I came to quite a few interesting bits of information:
A. after testing the approach mentioned by you, I found that I had to use 'stroke-dashoffset: 10' in the initial state and 'dashoffset: 0' in order for the animation to work.
B. I had to do it with plain CSS. Framer-motion did not interpolate between the values, no matter what I did with the transition.
C. The underlying problem is that my path is NOT closed. It seems like only closed paths can be animated in this way. Once I replaced it with, say, a circle, it worked well.